# corrupted image swift3 base64 django

Tags: ios, django, swift3, base64

I am trying to send an image from ios to my django server, using base64. All of the pieces seem to be working fine and there is no error, But the image saved in the django server is corrupted.
Below is my code for the ios side:

```
let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)! as NSData
let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithCarriageReturn)
```

where image is a UIImage. Then I send the json {'image',strBase64} to my django server. In the following you can find the code for the django side. This is the function which is called:

```
from base64 import b64decode

@csrf_exempt
def up(request):
    imageStr = request.POST.get('image','')
    if imageStr != '':
        image_data = b64decode(imageStr)
        Images.objects.create(pic = ContentFile(image_data,'image.jpg'))
        return HttpResponse("Image received.")
    return HttpResponse("No image received.")
```

and my model is like this:

```
class Images(models.Model):
    pic = models.ImageField("Image", upload_to = "images/")
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

And my django version is 1.10. I read the similar questions and the answers but none of them solved my problem.

Comment: Have you tried to log out the base64 string on both sides?

Comment: @AndreasPardeike Yes, The strings of both sides are the same.